# Analyze of programs (recursive)

Tags: c, recursion

I'm taking a C language course,and the lecturer loves to give a very complex recursive programs in the exam and ask what the call of the function does.
I would like to know some methods/tips for this kind of problems analyze.
Here is a question for example:

what does the following prog? (There are no computers on the exam)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int* what(int *arr, int *maxLen, int *curLen)
{
    int *res;
    if (*arr == -1){    
        *maxLen = *curLen = 0;
        return arr;
    }
    if (arr[1] == -1 ){
        *maxLen = *curLen = 1;
        return arr;
    }
    if (arr[2] == -1 ){
        *maxLen = *curLen = 2;
        return arr;
    }

    res = what(arr+1, maxLen, curLen);

    if ((arr[1] - arr[2]) * (*arr - arr[1]) > 0 ){
        *curLen = *curLen + 1;
        if ( *curLen >= *maxLen){
            *maxLen = *curLen;
            res = arr;
        }
    }else
        *curLen=2;

    return res;
}

void main(){
    int cur, max, i, j, *res, a[][20]= {{5,-1}, {5,6,-1}, 
        {1,4,5,9,7,6,4,6,9,8,5,4,1,4,5,6,-1}};

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        res = what(a[i], &max, &cur);
        printf("max=%d, ",max);
        for ( j = 0 ; j < max ; j++)
            printf("%d ", res[j]);
            ('\n');
    }
}//end
```

Comment: Draw the stack of calls

Comment: (There are no computers on the exam)

Comment: Simulate the program by drawing the stack of calls and/or run this program step by step in a debugger in order to "see what happens".

Comment: yea I'm trying to draw the stack,the problem is that there is only so much calls that I can do by hand,and sometimes there are some special cases that I can omit and therefor not understanding the purpose of the program.

Comment: Train to center yourself.

Answer (score 4):

If you have to analyze recursive code without any documentation (uncommon!), one approach is to treat it as you would a proof-by-induction:

1) Find the base case (the case where it returns without recursing). Understand what it does in that situation, for all the possible branches.

2) Then look at the recursive case. Understand what it's doing for the next-to-last case, using your understanding of the base case.

If necessary, repeat (2) until you understand the code.

As with other coding conventions, these become easier to "read" with practice

Note that this question isn't really specific to the C language; recursion is used in most languages, when appropriate. Some -- the "functional" languages -- use it particularly heavily.

Comment: maybe you have some internet resources on the topic?

Comment: If I did, I'd have cited them. I'm afraid this is simply a skill that you have to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try the program on paper..execute line by line,keeping record in a stack diagram and striking out and adding elements as removed and added.  Simple example is for finding factorial by recursion.
3!=3*(2!)->3*(2*(1!))->3*(2*(1)) returns 3*2->6

In exams use the working space and a pencil to try the execution